# nx command not found, nrwl installed globally

Tags: node.js, angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

```
user@machine folder % npm list -g | grep nrwl
├── @nrwl/cli@14.5.4
user@machine folder % nx --version
zsh: command not found: nx
```

Why is my command not found? Doesn't `nrwl` include the `nx` command?

Answer (score 1):

The `nrwl` team [purposefully removed it](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/9399#issuecomment-1072846205), probably from a namespace issue.